# How do you change the background opacity in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In CSS I can set the fg/bg opacity with the `opacity` property.  But I can't see how to change the background opacity without using `rgba()`.

This is annoying because I can't then use a color name with an opacity.

Example:

```html
<p style="background-color: red;">1: This is full opacity red<p>
<p style="background-color: red; opacity: 0.5">2: This is half opacity red<p>
<p style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);">3: This is full opacity red with rgba()<p>
<p style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);">4: This is full opacity red with rgba()<p>
<p style="background-color: red; background-opacity: 0.5">5: I'd like this to LOOK like #4, but it doesn't (because background-opacity is not real CSS)<p>
```

I'd LIKE to use CSS like shown example #5, but to have it WORK like example #4.

Comment: I use LESS personally, and with that I can write `fade(red, 50%)` to get the effect you want (it compiles to `rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`)

Comment: For reference: "No keyword-defined colors in CSS have any transparency, they are plain, solid colors." - [color @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: Is there any particular problem with #4 which gets solved with the #5 style?

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with using rgba? 0.5 = 50%

Comment: @Danield: using rgba I can't reference supported CSS color names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't see how to change the background opacity without using `rgba()`.

As pointed out in the comments, you could always use a CSS preprocessor to handle this.

For instance, [LESS's `fade()` color](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) function will take a color object and a percentage and convert the value to a usable `rgba` color:

```
p { background-color: fade(red, 50%); }
```

The above would compile to:

```
p { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

---

> I'd LIKE to use CSS like shown example #5, but to have it WORK like example #4.

#### Possible workaround:

Since you currently can't convert colors using CSS, one workaround would be to set the background color on a `:before` pseudo element. In doing so, you can still leverage the `opacity` property in order to adjust the opacity of the entire element without affecting the other element(s) and content.

```css
.background-opacity {
  position: relative;
}
.background-opacity:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="background-opacity">'background-color: red' / 'opacity: 0.5' on the ':before' pseduo element.<p>
```

Comment: This just results in the same css! Although, the workaround is good if it can fit in with the existing css classes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure setting background color opacity can only be done with rgba. the 'opacity' setting changes the opacity of the entire div and you've already discovered that 'background-opacity' is not a thing. You could maybe try something with sass or jquery to avoid losing the named colors, but that's honestly just a lot of overhead for something pretty simple.

tl;dr just use rgba and give up the string color name